# why does the probability function must add up to 1?

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ be a discrete random variable with the probability function $p(y)$. Then the expected value of $Y$, is define to be $\Bbb{E}(Y) = \sum_y p(y)$
(a) Briefly explain why the sum of all $y$, $p(y) = 1$.

The way I can think about this is problem is by the following : if I have a sample space that has $y = 0,1,2,.. n$, number of events and then corresponging probability of each event must add up to 1 because $1 = p(y_0) + p(y_1)+ p(y_2) + \cdots + p(y_n)$.

Is this correct? or is there a better way to explain it.

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is a defining property of probability function. So which axioms are you using?

Comment: It really is by definition.  But suppose it wasn't the case.  You sum over all the possibilities and you get a number less than 1, then that would suggest that there are possibilities that have not been accounted for.  Ann other way of thinking about it, is that you can always introduce a new case to plug the hole.  You have a coin that flips heads with 50% probability, and tails with 49% probability.  Then we can add a 3rd case, there is a 1% chance of seeing neither heads nor tails.  i.e. the coin lands on its edge, or it rolls under the sofa, or it spontaneously turns to dust.

Answer (score 1):

Talking in its numerical aspect, the probabilities always add up to $1$.

Why ?

Suppose you have a sample space $S$, and associated events $E_1, E_2, .... $ such that each event has a single outcome in the sample space (that's where I find it easy to explain). Now, the probability of each event will be $P(E_n) = \frac{1}{\text{(Size of}\space S)}$ (remember, each event has only one outcome associated with it as per what we've taken; for easier visualisation, take the case of a coin toss . Sample space $S = \lbrace {H, T} \rbrace$, required events : {possibility of a tail, possibility of a head} . Note that we can take other probabilities as well, for example, $P(\text{Getting either tail or head})$ or $P(\text{Getting none of them})$, but the ones we've taken have only one even associated with each).

Now, if we consider the example in the comment above, we can see that each even has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. Summing up the probabilities, we get $1$. This is how we get it:

1. $P(\text{Getting head}) = \frac{\lbrace H \rbrace}{\lbrace H, T\rbrace}$
2. $P(\text{Getting tail}) = \frac{\lbrace T \rbrace}{\lbrace H, T\rbrace}$
3. $P(\text{Getting head})+P(\text{Getting tail}) = \frac{\lbrace H \rbrace}{\lbrace H, T\rbrace} \cup \frac{\lbrace T \rbrace}{\lbrace H, T\rbrace} = \frac{\lbrace H, T \rbrace}{\lbrace H, T\rbrace} = P(\text{Getting head or tail}) $

In short , we are summing up all the outcomes (as said in the reply by @RGS ).

Do this example first to understand it properly.

If my math was wrong, sorry. I just did what I can to help you understand/ visualise the concept.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the axiomatic definition of probability, then we have

$$P(\Omega) = 1$$

where $\Omega$ denotes the whole space of events *i.e.* any possible outcome is in $\Omega$.

When you sum through all the values of $y $ you are summing up through all the possible outcomes. That means you are summing through all events in $\Omega $ and as we know (because of our definition of probability), $P(\Omega) = 1$.

Comment: I understand the following about the question but I having a hard time answering "(a) Briefly explain why...".   say we have a sample space S with n number of event E. So that S={E1,E2,E3,...En}. I understand that P(Ei) is between 0 and 1 and that P(S) = 1, where P(E1+E2+...En) = 1 by the axiom of probability.

Comment: @CesarAgama the brief explanation was the second paragraph